# Auto select radio buttons that are nested inside an li in a Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, this is my fist queston here in SO, and I'm still quite a noob.

I'm trying to apply this jquery code snippet (I found from other SO answers.

Basically, it's the same function that i'm trying to achieve but the markup structure is different because the inputs in my html structure are nested inside the li. 
Also, can anyone explain what does "% 3" do in this part of code .eq( ( $('input:checked').index() + 1 ) % 3 )

```js
  setInterval(function(){
     $('input').eq( ( $('input:checked').index() + 1 ) % 3 ).prop('checked', true);
  },1000);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="test-1">
      <input id="test-1" type="radio" name="testing" checked />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="test-2">
      <input id="test-2" type="radio" name="testing" />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="test-3">
      <input id="test-3" type="radio" name="testing" />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note: the markup structure can't be changed because it's how the wp plugin that i'm using is outputing its data.

Comment: check this for `%` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator

Comment: So i hope that you understand what the script is trying to do, right?

Comment: I didn't really get it from the link you gave, but it pointed me to the right direction, and I learned that it's called a modulus operator which outputs the remainder value.
In the case of the script: (0+1) % 3 = 1 , (1+1) % 3 = 2, (0+1) % 3 = 0
is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *can anyone explain what does "% 3" do in this part of code
>  `.eq( ( $('input:checked').index() + 1 ) % 3 )`*

That is more about maths than coding, But let's explain.

That `%` sign is a math operator called ["modulo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).
It is the remainder of a division.

Say 7/2 = 3.5

The modulo here is 1. Because the division gives 3 as an "entire" number, the quotient.
That is the part which could be divided without "cutting" it in parts (decimals)... Think about apples.

So 2 times 3 gives 6...

What's the remainder to have the original number?
That is the modulo.

```js
var number = 7;
var dividor = 2;

// Quotient
var quotient = Math.floor(number/dividor);
console.log(quotient);

// Modulo
var modulo = number%dividor;
console.log(modulo);

// Back to number...
var number2 = (quotient*dividor)+modulo;
console.log(number2);

console.log(number == number2);
```

**What's the use in your code sample now, step by step**:

An attempt is made to get the `$('input:checked').index()`...
And 1 is added the target the next one.
Then, we get the modulo of 3 for that index.

**Now** whatever which radio is clicked (indexes 0,1 or 2), the modulo alway is 1.
Because `.index()` used on an element and without argument passed to the method returns *«an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements»*. And in this case, it has no sibling within `label` in the markup.

Here is your snippet unmodified, but with jQuery lib loaded and some console logs for each part of the equation:

```js
setInterval(function(){
    $('input').eq( ( $('input:checked').index() + 1 ) % 3 ).prop('checked', true);
     
    console.log( $('input:checked').index() );
    console.log( ($('input:checked').index() + 1 )  );
    console.log( ($('input:checked').index() + 1 ) % 3 );
    console.log( "=====================================" );
     
  },1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="test-1">
      <input id="test-1" type="radio" name="testing" checked />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="test-2">
      <input id="test-2" type="radio" name="testing" />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="test-3">
      <input id="test-3" type="radio" name="testing" />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**The use of `.index()`**

If you want to cycle through the inputs, you can use `.index()`, **but** by passing the checked element as argument to the method applyed on the collection of all inputs.

```js
setInterval(function(){

  var indexOfChecked = $('input').index($("input:checked"));

  $('input').eq( ((indexOfChecked +1) %3 )).prop('checked', true);

  console.log( indexOfChecked );
  console.log( (indexOfChecked +1) );
  console.log( ((indexOfChecked +1) %3) );
  console.log( "=====================================" );

},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="test-1">
      <input id="test-1" type="radio" name="testing" checked />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="test-2">
      <input id="test-2" type="radio" name="testing" />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="test-3">
      <input id="test-3" type="radio" name="testing" />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The same thing could be achieved using `.each()` to find the index of the checked input, using the index of the each loop:

```js
setInterval(function(){

  var indexOfChecked = 0;

  $('input').each(function(index){
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
      indexOfChecked = index;
    }
  });

  $('input').eq( ((indexOfChecked +1) %3 )).prop('checked', true);

  console.log( indexOfChecked );
  console.log( (indexOfChecked +1) );
  console.log( ((indexOfChecked +1) %3) );
  console.log( "=====================================" );

},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="test-1">
      <input id="test-1" type="radio" name="testing" checked />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="test-2">
      <input id="test-2" type="radio" name="testing" />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="test-3">
      <input id="test-3" type="radio" name="testing" />
    </label>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**The use of `%`**

Here, it is to ensure the number used in `.eq()` will always be "in range" of existing elements.
The same thing could be achieved using a condition:

```
if( indexOfChecked > $('input').length-1 ){
  indexOfChecked = 0;
}
```

So your question finally was about maths regarding `%` **and** about `.index()` use.
There is a couple tricky twists like this subtile one in jQuery... You just have to know them.

[`.index()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/index/).
[`.eq()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful explanation!
 I get the math operator modulo part, what I don't get is how is the modulo always equal to 1 for whichever index is checked? 
From what  I understood, the code equation is like this 
(0+1) % 3 = 1 for index(0)  , (1+1) % 3 = 2 for index(1), (0+1) % 3 = 0 for index(2).  
So the script should run through 1, 2 , 0  indexes, what am I missing? 
Im sorry if this is a very noob question.

Comment: You're right to ask... The answer wasn't complete. I edited.

Comment: I upvoted your question, since I surprisingly had to work more than I taught at first, to define everything in detail... Your question isn't as noob as you think. ;)

Comment: WOW! You're amazing man! 
Your answer is thorough and perfect! Very well-explained.
I've learned a lot from it, why the original code didn't work for the markup and the work around twist for .index(), and you've even added a different approach :) 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks! That is a real cool comment. Hopefully, that explanation will be usefull to plenty of pleople over time. ;)