# jQuery - Rangeslider time update

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

My problem is the following:
I found a nice little fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/79ff562k/)* (the demo uses [rangeslider.js](http://rangeslider.js.org/)), and i want to change the percentange measurement to seconds (format is this: 00:00).
Can someone help or explain it to me?

```
$("#range-control").rangeslider({
    polyfill: false,
    onSlideEnd: function(position, value){
        audio.currentTime = audio.duration * value / 100;
    }
});

$(audio).bind('timeupdate', function(){
    var percent = audio.currentTime/ audio.duration * 100;
    $("#range-control").val(percent).change();
    $("#status").text(Math.round(percent*100)/100+"%");
});

$("#btn-play").click(function(){
    audio.play();
});

$("#btn-stop").click(function(){
    audio.pause();
});
```

Thanks!

*Well done, @alan0xd7

Comment: Have you tried anything in order to achieve this? Hint: use `currentTime` and just format it, then append it to `#status`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Louys Patrice Bessette. Could you help me a little bit with that?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer a bit more than just the time formatting here.
It is obvious that you wish to use the RangeSlider to have a custom audio control.

Depending on the event that triggers a need to change the displayed time, you have to use `currentTime` **or** `duration` multiplied by the slider position.

The two events in use are `timeupdate` from the audio element when it plays. And the `input` event when user moves the slider.

For those calculations, you will need the JavaScript [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) function to remove the decimals, when formating the time. You will also need to use the "modulo" operator to display the seconds correctly. [I already explained the use of modulo here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46066716/2159528).

And lastly, when the audio plays, I'm pretty sure you wish the slider to move accordingly with the time elapsed.

That make the function to have those three parts:

1. What to do when user moves the slider
2. What to to when the audio plays
3. And in all cases, update the displayed time.

So here is your function... I removed all console logs, but you can see them in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KXaKMr?editors=0011).

```
var audio = $("#audio")[0];

function displayTime(e){
  var newCurrentTime = 0;

  // User moves the slider. Just update the audio currentTime.
  if(e.type=="input"){
    newCurrentTime = audio.duration * parseInt( $("#range-control").val() ) / 100;
    audio.currentTime = newCurrentTime;
  }

  // The audio plays. Move the slider.
  if(e.type=="timeupdate"){
    newCurrentTime = audio.currentTime;        

    // Update the slider position
    var rangeSliderWidth = $(".rangeslider").width() - $(".rangeslider__handle").width();
    var audioPercent = audio.currentTime / audio.duration;
    var sliderPos = rangeSliderWidth*audioPercent;

    // The "handle" and the green fill at its left.
    $(".rangeslider__handle").css({"left":sliderPos});
    $(".rangeslider__fill").css({"width":sliderPos+21});
  }

  // Display formatted time
  var minutes = Math.floor(newCurrentTime/60);
  var seconds = Math.floor(newCurrentTime%60);
  if(seconds<10){seconds = "0"+seconds}
  $("#status").text(minutes+":"+seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way for me

```
<audio controls id="audio" hidden>
  <source type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<span id="handred"></span>
<script>
  var audio_time = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio_time.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};
  function myFunction() {
    var per_handred = (audio_time.currentTime * 100) / audio_time.duration;
    $('#handred').css('width',per_handred+'%')
  }
</script>
<style>
 #handred{
   height: 10px;
   display: block;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
 }
</style>
```